# Selected value in AntD Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using the AntD select component, and as you can see in the attached image, when selecting any of its options, AntD select displays "id" rather than "name." Is there a fix for this?

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
    const data = [
      {
        id: "5c83c2d0-e422-4eb6-b2cb-02fe60045e6e"
        name: "Item 1"
      },
      {
        id: "1b9175f9-750a-48c1-bbf7-0ff9a2fde7da"
        name: "Item 2"
      }
    ];

    return (
       <Select>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <Option value={item.id} key={item.id}>{item.name}</Option>
            )}
       </Select>
    );
};
```

[image]

Comment: @0stone0 I'm using https://ant.design/components/select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Ant design` `<Option>` has a prop named `label` to alter the shown text.

So instead of passing `item.name` as a child components, pass it as the `label` prop:

```
return (
   <Select>
        {data.map(item => (
            <Option value={item.id} key={item.id} label={item.name} />
        )}
   </Select>
);
```